# Archiva Artifacts Backup

Tags: apache, maven, jenkins, devops, archiva

Firstly, is it necessary to have BackUp of Artifacts stored in Apache Archiva?
If yes what would be the best practice and can we upload it into Amazon S3 buckets and retrieve later for Deploying it through using Docker Containers?

Answer (score 0):

according to the archiva home information[apache archiva specific information](https://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/Apache_Archiva-specific_information), just backup the user databases, so you can follow the instruction to stop archiva servers, then backup the user databases.